# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener?

Tags: java, csrf

I am working on  **OWASP-CSRFGuard 3.0**  ,But I am getting

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener** .

I kept this jar in lib folder **Owasp.CsrfGuard.jar** .And I kept  **csrfguard.properties** in **WEB-INF** Floder .Please check web.xml file below for configuration

```
     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardServletContextListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <listener>
        <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <context-param>
         <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/csrfguard.properties</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
         <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config.Print</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/save.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But I am getting below error

```
     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am also trying to get this working... did you get to the bottom of this problem?

Having looked in the JAR file provided by OWASP the classes

```
org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardServletContextListener
org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener
```

have not been included!

Answer (score 2):

Starting from version `4.0.0` of the csrftoken library, the `CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener` class has been moved to a separate maven dependency.

In your pom make sure to include the session extension next to the base library:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>csrfguard</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>csrfguard-extension-session</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```